# SVG Element Masking

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a theoretical question regarding SVG elements. I have several elements that I want to hide in plain sight. You can't query them with Jquery when they have a display of none. If I put an svg element at that same location with a fill of none while not changing the display of the jquery element, will jquery find the svg element or the regular element at that position?

Comment: The statement "You can't query them with Jquery when they have a display of none." is wrong.  So the answer to your question is that it would/could find both.

Comment: Maybe my wording is not quite right. If I use document.elementFromPoint on an element with a display of none it isn't found. My question I guess is is this the case with SVG elements too?